# Finding the smallest element in array in arm assembly

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, arm, min

I have this program that i have to write in arm assembly to find the smallest element in an array. Normally this is a pretty easy thing to do in every programming language, but i just can't get my head around what i'm doing wrong in arm assembly. I'm a beginner in arm but i know my way around c. So I wrote the algorithm on how to find the smallest number in an array in c like this.

```
int minarray = arr[0];
    for (int i =0; i < len; i++){
        if (arr[i] < minarray){
            minarray = arr[i];
        }
```

It's easy and nothing special really.
Now i tried taking over the algorithm in arm almost the same. There are two things that have already been programmed from the beginning. The address of the first element is stored in register r0. The length of the array is stored in register r1. In the end, the smallest element must be stored back in register r0. Here is what i did:

This is almost the same algorithm as the one in c. First i load the first element into a new register r4. Now the first element is the smallest. Then once again, i load the first element in r8. I compare those two, if r8 <= r4, then copy the content of r8 to r4. After that (because i'm working with numbers of 32 bits) i add 4bytes to r0 to get on to the next element of the array. After that i subtract 1 from the array length to loop through the array until its below 0 to stop the program.
The feedback i'm getting from my testing function that was given to us to check if our program works says that it works partly. It says that it works for short arrays and arrays of length 0 but not for long arrays. I'm honestly lost. I think i'm making a really dumb mistake but i just cannot find it and i've been stuck at this easy problem for 3 days now but everything i have tried did not work or as i said, only worked "partly". I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.
This is the feedback that i get:

- ✗ min works with other numbers
- ✗ min works with a long array
- ✓ min works with a short array
- ✓ min tolerates size = 0

(x is for "it does not work", ✓ is for "it works")

So you see what i'm saying? i just do not understand how to implement the fact that its supposed to work with a longer array.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the loop `for (int i =0; i < len; i++)` could start with index `1` instead: `for (int i =1; i < len; i++)`

Comment: Instead of describing your code in a fairly long text block, I suggest to write the explanation to every code line in your assembly code in form of a comment.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. i'll do that the next time!

Comment: So, you're saying that in the assembly version (as compared with the C version), you've changed it from array references to using pointers and from a for/while loop form that counts up, to a do-while loop that counts down.  All of these changes can be done in C, and I recommend doing these optimizations all in C first, make sure they're working by testing.  What's the point of pseudo code or C code if you don't follow it in assembly?  (And a do-while will iterate at least once, by definition.)

Comment: Btw, it is inappropriate to access arr[0] if the array length is 0, that is a logic error in your C code.

Comment: @ErikEidt yes, you are right, thank you. i have not thought about that. I know my way around c enough to say i'm not a total beginner, but still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very good at ARM assembly by to my understanding R4 is expected to keep the value of minimum. R8 is used to keep the most recently fetched value from the input array.

The minimum is updated with this instruction:

```
MOVLE   r8, r4
```

But it actually updated R8, not R4.

Try:

```
MOVLE   r4, r8
```

---

EDIT

Other issue is using incorrect branch instruction:

```
SUBS    r1, r1, #1 
BPL     loop1
```

works like:

```
r1 = r1 - 1
if (r1 >= 0) goto loop1;
```

For R1 equal to `1` the loop is exectured **twice**.

```
r1 = 1
... do stuff
r1 = r1 - 1 // r1 is 0 now
if (r1 >= 0) goto loop1;     // 0>=0 TRUE!
... do stuff, overflow the input by indexing at `[r0 + 4]`
r1 = r1 - 1 // r1 is -1
if (r1 >= 0) goto loop1;     // -1 >= 0   FALSE
// exit function
```

To fix it use branching only when input is non-zero.

```
BNE loop1
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. You are right, that was a mistake i just saw. But the output with this instruction is 0.

Comment: by output do you mean the value stored in `r0` after the function is called? what were the values of `R1` and the data pointer by `[R0]`?

Comment: yes, the first value is stored in r0. and the length is stored in register r1. is that what you mean? i basically got a bunch of extra files with this assignment that work in the backround. Then i was given the assembly file and the only comments were: Arguments: // r0: Array Address // r1: Array length // return value : r0

Comment: @someblonde, the the updated answer

Comment: yes i get what you are saying because i tried this before. the problem tho is that this makes the program work only partly. This is the feedback that i get: ✗ min works with other numbers | ✗ min works with a long array | ✓ min works with a short array| ✓ min tolerates size = 0 |(x is for "it does not work", ✓ is for "it works") so you see what i'm saying? i just do not understand how to implement the fact that its supposed to work with a longer array.

Comment: @someblonde, please put those requirements into the question. It is a crucial information for providing a correct solution. Btw. what value should be returned for size=0? INT_MIN?

Comment: @ tstanisl it does not say anything about what should be returned for size = 0. I also thought that naturally, the function should work for arrays of any size. I don't even understand what a short and a long array is supposed to look like? And what is meant by "does not work for other numbers"?I'll make sure to write more detailed questions next time. This is my first time

Comment: @someblonde, this `size=0` case is very pathological. I suggest putting `CMP r1, #0; MOVEQ pc, lr;` at the start of your function to cut off this case

Comment: Thank you for the help, finally got it right.

Answer (score 0):

1. Coding in C use the correct types
2. You do not have to iterate from the index `0` only `1`

```
int foo(const int *arr, size_t len)
{
    int minarray = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < minarray)
        {
            minarray = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return minarray;
}
```

And it generates this code:

```
foo:
        mov     r3, r0
        subs    r1, r1, #1
        ldr     r0, [r3], #4
        beq     .L1
.L3:
        ldr     r2, [r3], #4
        cmp     r0, r2
        it      ge
        movge   r0, r2
        subs    r1, r1, #1
        bne     .L3
.L1:
        bx      lr
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! Firstly, why are you using a pointer in the foo function? And secondly, could you maybe please explain what was wrong with my code in arm assembly? Yours is very different to mine and i still do not understand why mine does not work.

Comment: @someblonde: Because passing a pointer + length is how you pass an array to a function in C (or asm), and incrementing a pointer is standard for looping over arrays.  If you wrote the loop in the same C function that initialized the array, a good optimizing compiler would just do constant propagation and remove the loop.

Comment: @someblonde:  As far as why yours doesn't work, 0___________ often posts answers like this to debugging questions, completely ignoring the debugging question and just dumping a working implementation from compiler output.  (Understanding why the compiler output works is a useful way to learn, but this answer isn't doing much to help you with that, not even commenting it.)  (Questions like this have pretty low future value, since even if someone did have an identical bug or misconception, they'd be unlikely to be able to find this Q&A.  Showing how toget good compiler output is semi-relevant.)

Comment: @someblonde do you have debugger? Simply execute instruction by instruction and see what is going wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes, okay, thank you.   still have a lot to learn. This code works, but it changes my whole code and indeed does not help as to why mine doesn't work.

Comment: @0___________ no i don't. Firstly, i use the servers from uni to even compile and run the code and secondly, because i use unis server, i can't download debuggers. I have macOS Big Sur M1. Any suggestions for a debugger?

Comment: @someblonde hard to believe that uni did not provides basic debugging tools. I am 100% sure that you can find gdb installed on your uni server

Comment: @0___________ i know right? Well that was a homework once. Debugging a program in c with gdb. gdb does not work on mac m1. so i went to uni to try using it on the uni computers. It indeed was not installed. I tried installing it but of course i could't, because i don't have rights to just install stuff.

Comment: @someblonde: You definitely need to use a debugger if you want to learn asm by playing around with code; doing so without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfolded.  It's a waste of your own time, and everyone else's.  Single-stepping and watching registers change is very helpful to see what's going on if you can't visualize / simulate it in your head.

Comment: @someblonde:   If you're not sure how to use a debugger on your school computers, ask your instructor how to do that.  (Also, MacOS XCode should come with a debugger like `lldb`, and have a visual debugger with the IDE.  But it might only be able to do ARM64 code, not 32-bit ARM, because I think the M1 CPU only supports executing in 64-bit mode.  So you might need an ARM32 simulator with a debugger.)

Comment: @PeterCordes well yes, it does feel like a waste of time without debugger. I'm going to try to use one.

Comment: @someblonde: And BTW, a debugger doesn't require setuid root or anything; you should be able to install one in your home directory on a Unix or Linux server if you can create files that have exec permission.  Assuming it's an actual ARM32 machine; it ARM binaries are emulated with qemu, then you'd want qemu options to let a remote GDB attach.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with the debugger!